# Classifying excel workbooks based on "string name" at specific location of excel sheet

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, readxl

I am working with ~30 excel workbooks containing data with different set of designs. However, excel sheets within workbook are well formatted.

```
# There is a pattern, wherein if we have string "System setting" at 
# i.e., 
df[4,4] == "System setting"  #(then it is single core setup)

# Similarly,
df[4,6] == "System setting" # (then it is double core setup)
df[4,9] == "System setting" # (then it is triple core setup)
```

Now, I want to classify all of workbooks based on this information; whether their system setting is of single core, double core or triple core.

I tried following.

```
# Creating list of file names within folder
file_list <- list.files(pattern = '*.xlsx')
file_list

# Extracting sheet of interest as list of dataframes
Setup <- sapply(file_list, function(i){
  x = read_excel(i, sheet = "Setup")
  x
}, simplify = F, USE.NAMES = T)

# Now looking for specific information at cell location, this is for specifically identify sheets with single core 
Check_single_core <- for (i in Setup){
                        x = i[4,4]
                        x
                     }
```

There are 11 out of 30 files have string, "System setting" at this location (i.e., i[4,4])
However, output over here is null.

I also tried this with lapply

```
Check_single_core_2 <- lapply(Setup, function(j){
  y = j[4,4]
  y
})
```

However, this generates list of 30 tibbles. All of them are blank.

I would like to understand how I can resolve this and further classify all of them under correct category.

Comment: Reading an excel file into R does not necessarily mean a perfectly formed matrix.  Are there blank rows or columns?  I suggest reading in a problem file to confirm it is what you expect.

Comment: They are formatted and value (i.e., "System setting") is present at cell (i.e., i[4,4]).

Comment: Please edit your question and include the results of `i[1:4,1:4]` for one of your problem files.  I believe you have a blank cell(s) in the spreadsheet, causing the row/column count to be off.  Maybe a merge cell... Not enough information is provided to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: @Dave2e I guess changing the strategy worked for me. I rather picked complete row 4 and then created the new data frame where we have row 4 of all dataframes combined.

`Check_file_type_2 <- sapply(Setup, function(j){
  y = j[4,]
  y
})

Setup_summary <- do.call(rbind.fill, Check_file_type_2)
Setup_summary$Result_file_name <- file_list
`

Comment: As a next step to sort them all, I am writing ifelse statement to add one more column in the dataframe Setup_summary.

`Setup_summary$Setup <- if(Setup_summary$...4 == "System setting"){print("Single core")} else if (Setup_summary$...6 == "System setting" && Setup_summary$...3 == "Second core"){ print("Double core")} else {print("Triple core")}`

However, there are errors, "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" and "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Answer (score 0):

If the information is in a specific cell in your excel files, you could use the following approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- FALSE

path_To_Excel_File <- "D:/excel_File.xlsx"
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_Excel_File)

xlWbk$Sheets(1)$Range("B2")$Value()
```

You could also consider the following approach to read a specific cell :

```
library(readxl)
read_excel(path_To_Excel_File, range = "B2")
```

Once you have the information you can use it to classify the excel files.